# Нарисовать линию поверх кнопок

Tags: c#, wpf, графика

В WPF приложении выводятся кнопки в виде похожем на экранную клавиатуру, но не точно также. Хотелось бы рисовать линию движения мыши так, как это сделано в blind texting

[image]
<sub>(источник: [microsoft.com](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/news/features/images/grouped_key.jpg))</sub>

Посмотрел классы в WPF, но их очень много, и ничего не нашел подходящего. Подскажите как нарисовать линию поверх кнопок и других элементов на странице WPF-приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Легко! Положите сверху прозрачный для мыши канвас.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button>Q W E</Button>
        <Button>R T Y U</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <Canvas IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <Line X1="15" Y1="15" X2="500" Y2="40" Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="4"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Результат:

[image: оверлей]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но это не то, дело в том, что вы нарисовали Line, а мне надо линию движения мыши, как об этом я и спрашивал в вопросе. Линия движения мыши другими словами - это траектория движения мыши и она может быть волнистой, кривой, зигзагом, ну то есть любой, как того пожелает тот, кто управляет мышью.

Comment: @Grizlov, а как это влияет на совет использовать прозрачный для событий канвас?